# Capacitance on floating terminals of a multimeter

Tags: capacitor, multimeter

Why does a multimeter show some capacitance when its terminal are not connected to any capacitor?

My multimeter is showing 30pF. Does this imply that my multimeter is not calibrated properly or it is due to humidity in the atmosphere or something else?

Comment: Do you have probes connected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is always going to be stray capacitance on the inputs to a meter, this will read as an offset.

Calibration would be used to adjust the overall scale of the reading, but for an offset what you want is to zero the meter. Many capacitance meters have an auto-zero function, you push a button with no capacitor attached and it basically takes whatever stray capacitance it reads and subtracts that from the result.

Whether or not your meter has such a function I can't say without knowing the model, but you can look at it and see if there is a button for that or get the instruction manual. There may be a control to adjust the zero reading such as a small pot accessible through a hole in the case, but most modern cap meters do it with a button.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Yes I use the "Null" button on my multimeter but i have to set it to null everytime I'm using.

Comment: @Technaut Yes, that's normal because the stray capacitance can change depending on the leads you have connected, placement of the meter and leads, nearby metal objects such as a wood bench vs. a metal bench, etc., so you should null it each time.

Answer (score 1):

Any 2 conductors separated by an insulator will exhibit some amount of capacitance. In the case of a typical multimeter, the connections to the multimeter are metal and separated by air and plastic. Thus there will be a small capacitance between them, usually a few pF. When you connect the leads the capacitance will increase since you now have several feet of copper wire. If you separate the leads, the capacitance will decrease. If you wrap the leads together, the capacitance will increase. This is normal behavior for almost all measuring equipment. In most cases, it is small enough to ignore. For oscilloscopes, however, the input capacitance has a significant effect and is dealt with by adding a compensating adjustment to scope probes.